# Selected option value is not passed to modal using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an edit `jQuery modal` that gets values passed to it via `jquery` and `data attributes` passed through a `button`. When the `jQuery modal` is displayed, all the other values show apart from the `select's option` (with name and id measure). I can't seem to figure out the problem. Here is my code:

HTML code

```
    <button id="editButton" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-id="<?php echo $r->ingredientId;?>" 
    data-ing="<?php echo $r->ingredientName;?>" data-brand="<?php echo $r->brand;?>" data-measure="<?php echo $r->measureName;?>" 
    data-measureId="<?php echo $r->measure;?>" data-quantity="<?php echo $r->quantity;?>" data-price="<?php echo $r->price;?>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
     label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modify Ingredient</h4>
   </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();>index.php/MainController/ingredients/edit">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="hidden"name="uid" id="uid"/>
  <label for="ingredient">Ingredient Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ingredient" name="ingredient" required/>
<label for="brand">Brand Name:</label>
<input name="brand" id="brand" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
<label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
<input name="quantity" id="quantity"class="form-control" type="text" required/>
<label for="measure">Measure:</label>
<select name="measure" id="measure" class="form-control" required>
   <?php foreach ($measure as $m) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo $m->measureId;?>"><?php echo $m->measureName;?></option><?php }?>
 </select>
 <label for="price">Price:</label>
 <input name="price" id="price" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
 </div>
```

....

Jquery Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", '#editButton',function(e) 
    {
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     var ingredient = $(this).data('ing');
     var brand = $(this).data('brand');
     var quantity = $(this).data('quantity');  
     var measure = $(this).data('measure'); 
     var measureId = $(this).data('measureId'); 
     var price = $(this).data('price'); 

     $("#uid").val(id);
     $("#ingredient").val(ingredient);
     $("#brand").val(brand);
     $("#quantity").val(quantity);
     $("#measure").val(measureId);
     $("#price").val(price);
     $("#measure").val(measureId);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: does the value comes in js variable ? try to console it first

Comment: Please verify that you have "measureId" value or not, use console.log() and hit  $("#measure").val("SOMETHING_HARD_CODED_ID"); from developer console, try to debug issue.

Comment: Scale this down to a [mcve] that isolates only the relevant html and doesn't include server code but actual html. Your server code is useless to us

Comment: @Rush.2707  I have tried console.log(measureId) it returns undefined but when I use a hardcoded value like $("#measure").val(3) it shows the option on the modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue is with your data's name,

data can not count Capital cases. "`measureId`" is only one having "I" as capital latter.

Try making it small, like "measureid".

You can see my example code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($('#test123').data('measerId'));
alert($('#test123').data('measerid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-measerId="sdbhfj" id="test123" />
```

Due to this error your variable is not getting value it should have and further thing would not be done.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
  $("#uid").val(id);
```

try this

```
 $('#uid').val('"'+id+'"');
```

[jQuery.val] checks, or selects, all the radio buttons, checkboxes, and select options that match the set of values.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this .

```
$("select#measure").val(measureId).change();
```